# How to implement "Mint" and "Own" in an ERC20 Token

Tags: erc-20, openzeppelin-contracts, mint

So, I recently created a standard ERC20 token but I need to implement "mint" and "owner" functionality. I see that in older implementations but openzeppelin no longer has contracts like "Mintable" and "Ownable". How do I implement this "mint" functionality?  I do see it in ERC20.sol but not able to test it in console(truffle).

Answer (score 5):

They are still internal functions of the ERC-20 contract, see [docs](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/api/token/erc20#ERC20-_mint-address-uint256-). So you can simply create a new contract that inherits from that one and add the `mint` function:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.10;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract MintableToken is Ownable, ERC20 {
    constructor() public ERC20("Gold", "GLD") { }

    function mint(address account, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
        _mint(account, amount);
    }

    function burn(address account, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
        _burn(account, amount);
    }
}
```

Comment: how did you set owner of the contract?

Comment: In the current version of Ownable you could e.g. do `constructor(address originalOwner) Ownable(originalOwner) ERC20("Gold", "GLD") {}`.